# Add an `.inc` file to an assembly language project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, masm, irvine32

In Visual Studio 2010, how can I add an `.inc` file to an assembly language project? Here, I'm trying to add `irvine32.lib` to the project:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: p10, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'irvine32.lib'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I got this error when I added this line at the start of the `.asm` file:

```
include irvine32.inc
```

Answer (score 2):

```
include PATHTOIRVINE\irvine32.inc
includelib PATHTOIRVINE\irvine32.lib
```